# Call to a member function $CI object codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I tried to call a method `getTemplate` from class `InitTemplate`

At first I load library:

```
$this->CI->load->library('InitTemplate', $this->posts);
```

After call method:

```
 $view = $this->CI->InitTemplate->getTemplate();
```

I get error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on a non-object
>   in line $this->CI->InitTemplate->getTemplate();

If put `echo 'test';` in constructor InitTemplate, it works

This is a constructor of class where is loaded a library:

```
public function __construct($data){
        $this->CI = & get_instance();

    }
```

Comment: What is this `CI` here? Can you please put a little more of your code?

Comment: The library is loaded, I told about this in question, but method does not call